# Image Slides using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

This code is running well on another machine but on my laptop not doing well. It is about image sliding.
I am using google chrome browser.

I have do the same code on my machine using VSCode editor.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>JavaScript Image Slides</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/slide.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="slider">
    <h2>JavaScript Image slider Project</h2>
    <hr>
    <img src="images/21.jpg" id="firstImage" alt="No image">
  </div>
<!-- <script src="slide.js"></script> -->

    <script>
       var images = [
    "11.jpg",
    "21.jpg",
    "31.jpg",
    "4.jpg",
    "5.jpg",
    "6.jpg",
    "7.jpg",
    "8.jpg",
    "9.jpg",
    "10.jpg"
    ];

var i=0;
  function slide(){
      document.getElementById("firstImage").src=images[i];
      if (i<(images.length-1)) 
          i++;
          else
          i=0;


  }

   setInterval(slide, 1000);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

================================
External css file.
js is inside the html file.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: are you getting any errors?

Comment: "not doing well" is a statement not a question. Please describe what you mean by "not doing well" (eg. errors) and what you've done to in trying to it.